# css div positioning correction needed

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css

I just embedded the Jquery News Ticker in my site  [The Kashmir Scenario](http://www.thekashmirscenario.com) , but i want the ticker to take the 60% width of the page so that the div with class ".threecol_three" shifts up to acquire the left over space above it but some how it does'nt do that , i tried applying 'float and display' commands in the css.....but it does'nt seem to work..

Here's the css code :

```
.threecol_three {
   width:303px;
   float:right;
   margin-bottom:56px;
}

.ticker-wrapper.has-js {

margin: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
padding: 0px 20px;
width: 580px;
height: 32px;
display: block;
-webkit-border-radius: 15px;
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
border-radius: 15px;
background-color: #f8f0db;
font-size: 0.75em;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the three divs "threecol_one", "threecol_two" and "ticker-wrapper" in one div that floats to the left.

Edit

Another solution:

Inside the div with id "content" is a div with the id of "also" and "bottom". So the sections are nicely wrapped for better control. Maybe you could group "ticker-wrapper", "threecol_one", "threecol_two" and "threecol_three" like you did with the other two sections. Then you could try the example below.

Example:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="ticker-wrapper">
    </div>
    <div class="threecol_one">
    </div>
    <div class="threecol_two">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="threecol_three">
</div>

#wrapper{
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: How about adding "margin-top: -30px" to div with class "threecol_three"?

Comment: Or you could try to give the div with class "threecol_three" a "float:  right; "

Comment: @MajidZargar perhaps you could provide a reason as to why you can't do that? It'll be easier to help you if we know your limitations.

Comment: @Zhihao ... i have a "#wrap" starting from the ticker and ending at almost the the footer and giving it a "float:left;" takes the whole content towards the left